# Dream Job no longer giving Bux

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

I have found that recently, placing bitizens in their dream jobs only gives me back imperial bux maybe 50% of the time (seems like less, but I haven't actually counted).  I also get two different messages now when I do get the bux.

One being the original, and now:

Header: Dream Job 
"TODO DESIGN: You gave so-and-so their dream job and earned 1 Imperial Bux"

There doesn't seem to be any continuity as to what levels give bux and which don't.  I can put two bitizens in the same level and one will get a bux and the next won't.

Is this a glitch? I've continually evicted and restocked my bitizen in order to unlock all the characters, but this started to just before I unlocked my last (non-galactic registry) character and before the most recent update.

Comment: Are you putting the *same* Bitizens into their dream job? They'll only give Bux for their dream job once per bitizen

Comment: No, these are new bitizens.  Interestingly, after getting the Endor Adventure, it gave me 3 bux for the first 3 bitizens, but after evicting them and shuffling through the rest of my new bitizens, no more bux.  Perhaps they're capping levels for certain periods of time?

Comment: "TODO Design" sounds like an unfinished feature.

Answer (score 3):

I'm seeing the same thing. I started a new game on a different device and interestingly, all the new dream jobs scored 1 bux 100% of the time. However, once I started evicting dream job employees (or unemploying them) I was consistently getting no bux for new dream job bitzens. I did this because I was curious if I was re-hiring bitzens that had earlier been evicted. This couldn't be the case in a new game. So yes, this is depressing because this was a fantastic way to make bux...and fast. I was earning 150 - 200 per day with only a 40 level death star. My strategy has been to build only one residence per retail level. This gives 2 empty apts to hold dream jobs while I'm restocking. It's such an effective technique. Now that the bux are spotty at best I've deleted my star. I don't mind restarting if this ever gets fixed, but for now I'm putting it down.

Wednesday Update:
Let us know if that worked. I deleted the game for now, but if that works then maybe I'll fire it up again. I don't mind chasing down the bux for elevators!

Answer (score 1):

I observed the same thing, dozens of times this weekend.  I hardly ever get bux from putting **brand new people** in dream jobs anymore.  I'm using Android.

I airlocked one person from every floor, and I have all the previously available floors, so virtually every time my elevator takes someone to the bottom half of my tower, that person is eligible to be put in their dream job right away. First, I observed that the words "TODO DESIGN" were popping up in the message telling me I just earned a Bux, but I was still earning the Bux, so I ignored it.  But now, about 90% of the time I put a brand new person in their dream job, no Bux.  They just get dropped in, as if I'd already claimed the bux for them.

For a short time, I observed the moving levels around my tower fixed the problem temporarily, but that doesn't seem to work anymore either.

I was willing to give this event a chance, and I savaged my tower to maximize my bux-earning potential, all for nothing, because now I can't earn Bux that way.

UPDATE:

I got a response from Support, they suggesting clearing the cache, restarting the device, then reconnect through wifi...it didn't quite work.  But the TODO DESIGN message changed.  I get bux about half the time I should.  It seems to be sort of floor dependent, but I haven't worked out a pattern yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have also noticed the same behavior: actions that used to result in the bonus 1 bux for a dream job placement no longer do that.  I did an experiment to test the hypothesis that the removal was because of the rapid turnover as follows:

A) New arrival arrives with skill level less than 9 for a level which is already filled with skill 9 dream jobbers.  Do the usual: assign no job to one of the skill 9's temporarily, immediately hire the lower skill one, see if I get the bux reward, then evict the new arrival and hire back the old skill 9.

B) Same thing, but with a significant time delay before hiring the lower-skill level new arrival.  I tried for about 5 minutes of leaving the level with only 2 workers while waiting a bit, stocking other levels, etc.

Method A did not give any bux rewards, but Method B did give the usual single bux reward.

I did method A five times and method B once.  So perhaps the removal of the bux reward is only for very short vacancies.

Edit: I've done method B again and got a reward bux from that time as well.  This is on iOS with data file 1.4.0.5  Another update: the "wait to hire" method B continues to give reward bux.

Comment: That doesn't match my observations.  I airlocked a person from every floor when the event started.  Every floor has the third worker either sitting unemployed or airlocked, and it's been like that for a week.  And I still only get bux about a third of the time.  I've observed that I'm more likely to get bux with 9 skill level people, but lots of level 9's don't give me a bux, and people lower than that often do.

Comment: @swbarnes2: Aha, that is useful information.  It is strange that the behavior is erratic- I thought the time delay might have something to do with it and I will experiment more. From your experience, it seems not.

Comment: Replacing a 9 with a 9 seems to give bucks, replacing a 9 with an 8 does as well, but replacing a 9 with a 5 does not. Wondering if they are keeping you from farming bux by putting low skill workers in place of high.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into it, you only earn extra dream job bux through workers of a higher dream job skill level, than the one you are replacing.

Comment: That does not match my own observations

Answer (score 0):

Yes, occasionally Bitzens do not give Bux for being put in their dream job. More often then not, they still do give bux, but I have noticed that maybe 1 in 10 for me does not give bux. The level of the bitizen does not seem to matter. I've had skill 9 bitizens that have not given bux.